# If $P$ is false, and $Q$ is true, then why does $P \implies Q$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have often seen truth tables similar to this one:

[image]

The first two rows, where $P$ is true, make sense to me. However, why does $P$ being true and $Q$ being false mean that $P \implies Q$?

To make the question clearer to myself, I came up with the following example: let $P$ be whether or not it is raining. Let Q be whether or not I am wearing a coat. Then, there are $4$ possibilities:

> It is raining; I am wearing a coat. 
>  It is raining; I am not
> wearing a coat. 
>  It is not raining; I am wearing a coat. 
>  It
> is not raining; I am not wearing a coat.

$P \implies Q$ is the same as saying *if it is raining, then I will wear a coat*. This statement says nothing about what happens when it is not raining. Therefore, why do we say *not raining* $\implies$ *coat*?

Comment: You can look [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Info/People/gries/symposium/clarke.htm) for a good explanation for what regards material implication

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes it does. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that, in mathematics, "$P \implies Q$" is equivalent to "$Q$ or not $P$". Thus if $Q$ is true, $Q$ or not $P$ is also true, whatever $P$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can wear a coat when it's not raining, for example when it's snowing.

More generally, $P$ has an influence on the state of $Q$, **not** the other way around, which is why the arrow is shown in one way only. If you consider a two-way relation, for example $P \iff Q$, then both have an influence on the state of the other. For example when $P$ denotes *eating no meat* and $Q$ denotes *being a vegetarian* (although one might find easier examples).